# Install server 2003 in already windows 7 installed machine as dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-server-2003

I have a Laptop which installed windows 7 genuine. But there are only one partition. I want to install Server 2003 as dual boot. Can I do it without format the laptop and keep the data already in the laptop??
please help me

Answer (score 1):

This guide, while written for installing Windows XP alongside an existing Windows 7 installation, should be enough to get you going.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8790/dual-boot-your-pre-installed-windows-7-computer-with-xp/

I've read through the guide, and none of it looks like it would have an issue with Server 2003, but, as it's a process involving your hard drive and the data contained within, I suggest you take a full image of the drive or a backup of all your data before you make any changes with the guide.

Hope this helps :)

regards,

Steve